# How to replicate data between original replicaset and new replicaset

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb replicaset installed on my original host (k8s cluster 1) and i have just installed a new mongodb replicaset on the new host (k8s cluster 2).

**My goal is to replicate the data from the original host to the new host, so that i can shutdown the old host.**

There is a blog post that im trying to follow to achieve this however im having some trouble. (reference: https://mschmitt.org/blog/mongodb-migration-replicaset/)

**original_host**: aadfad22ca65e4ff09de37179f961d5b-.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017

**new_host**: ab775d626d81742478af2744923e2ec6-.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017

**ATTEMPT**

1. I tried to step down the **new host** with `rs.stepDown({force:true})`. However it fails....

```
 rs.stepDown({force:true})
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "No electable secondaries caught up as of 2022-05-24T08:50:24.809+00:00. Please use the replSetStepDown command with the argument {force: true} to force node to step down.",
        "code" : 262,
        "codeName" : "ExceededTimeLimit",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1653382215, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"qugjVF4xVS8+MNYlCgkK+0/Jt1o="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("7100922576402120709")
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1653382211, 1)
}
```

2. I tried to add the new_host as a rs member to the original rs using `rs.add( { host: "ab775d626d81742478af2744923e2ec6-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017", priority: 0, votes: 0 } )` However it fails with `replica set IDs do not match`

```
             {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "ab775d626d81742478af2744923e2ec6-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017",
                        "health" : 0,
                        "state" : 8,
                        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                        "uptime" : 0,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:52:21.889Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "replica set IDs do not match, ours: 628c90e7c07f5017faff8b75; remote node's: 628b8b76ab0cdc7f9158b23b",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : -1,
                        "configTerm" : -1
                }
```

**original replicaset config**

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "rs0",
        "date" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:48.912Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(2),
        "syncSourceHost" : "",
        "syncSourceId" : -1,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "majorityVoteCount" : 2,
        "writeMajorityCount" : 1,
        "votingMembersCount" : 2,
        "writableVotingMembersCount" : 1,
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1653381945, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                },
                "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:45.660Z"),
                "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1653381945, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                },
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1653381945, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1653381945, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                },
                "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:45.660Z"),
                "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:45.660Z")
        },
        "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1653381945, 1),
        "electionCandidateMetrics" : {
                "lastElectionReason" : "electionTimeout",
                "lastElectionDate" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:01:45.606Z"),
                "electionTerm" : NumberLong(2),
                "lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                        "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                },
                "lastSeenOpTimeAtElection" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1653379303, 15),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "numVotesNeeded" : 1,
                "priorityAtElection" : 5,
                "electionTimeoutMillis" : NumberLong(10000),
                "newTermStartDate" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:01:45.609Z"),
                "wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:01:45.611Z")
        },
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "aadfad22ca65e4ff09de37179f961d5b-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 2644,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1653381945, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(2)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:45Z"),
                        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:45.660Z"),
                        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:45.660Z"),
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1653379305, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:01:45Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 7,
                        "configTerm" : 2,
                        "self" : true,
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "mongodb-staging-arbiter-0.mongodb-staging-arbiter-headless.staging.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 7,
                        "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                        "uptime" : 2627,
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:47.161Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:47.763Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 7,
                        "configTerm" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "ab775d626d81742478af2744923e2ec6-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017",
                        "health" : 0,
                        "state" : 8,
                        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                        "uptime" : 0,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:47.280Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "replica set IDs do not match, ours: 628c90e7c07f5017faff8b75; remote node's: 628b8b76ab0cdc7f9158b23b",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : -1,
                        "configTerm" : -1
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1,
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1653381945, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"1GVq5OEAV3YzQmhPHuzQPVwC7+c="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("7101210034268274693")
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1653381945, 1)
}
```

**new replicaset config**

```
{
        "set" : "rs0",
        "date" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:52.621Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(6),
        "syncSourceHost" : "",
        "syncSourceId" : -1,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "majorityVoteCount" : 2,
        "writeMajorityCount" : 1,
        "votingMembersCount" : 2,
        "writableVotingMembersCount" : 1,
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1653381951, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(6)
                },
                "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:51.410Z"),
                "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1653381951, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(6)
                },
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1653381951, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(6)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1653381951, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(6)
                },
                "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:51.410Z"),
                "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:51.410Z")
        },
        "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1653381921, 1),
        "electionCandidateMetrics" : {
                "lastElectionReason" : "electionTimeout",
                "lastElectionDate" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:42:31.402Z"),
                "electionTerm" : NumberLong(6),
                "lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                        "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                },
                "lastSeenOpTimeAtElection" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1653381732, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(5)
                },
                "numVotesNeeded" : 1,
                "priorityAtElection" : 5,
                "electionTimeoutMillis" : NumberLong(10000),
                "newTermStartDate" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:42:31.405Z"),
                "wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:42:31.407Z")
        },
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "ab775d626d81742478af2744923e2ec6-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 204,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1653381951, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(6)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:51Z"),
                        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:51.410Z"),
                        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:51.410Z"),
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1653381751, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:42:31Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 4,
                        "configTerm" : 6,
                        "self" : true,
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "mongodb-prod-arbiter-0.mongodb-prod-arbiter-headless.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 7,
                        "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                        "uptime" : 187,
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:50.898Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2022-05-24T08:45:52.493Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "configVersion" : 4,
                        "configTerm" : 6
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1,
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1653381951, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"XYfuUbFoIwFfLZx3FqPOAD+CU44="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("7100922576402120709")
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1653381951, 1)
}
```

Comment: Replication is expensive and slow. You are using AWS - mount an efs volume to both primaries, ssh to the source, run mongodump to efs, ssh to the destination, run mongorestore from efs.  Regarding the error - did you confirm your k8s ingres/egres settings to allow mongo instances to communicate?  the original rsconfig says the new secondary is not reachable.

Comment: Im aware i could do mongodump and mongorestore, but i'd like to avoid chance of losing any data. I want a solution where im able to mirror the data

Answer (score -1):

Drop all data from new hosts, i.e. stop mongod, delete all files from `dbPath` and start again.

Then simply add new hosts as new member, i.e. `rs.add("ab775d626d81742478af2744923e2ec6-.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017")` Once you added them, an initial sync is running. Check sync with `rs.status()`, it may take some time.

When the new members are in state `SECONDARY` and `rs.printSecondaryReplicationInfo()` shows

```
rs.printSecondaryReplicationInfo()
source: "aadfad22ca65e4ff09de37179f961d5b-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017"
        syncedTo: Tue May 24 2022 11:23:23 GMT+0200 (CEST)
        0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary
```

(1-2 sec. behind the primary is also normal) then you can remove the old host from replica set with `rs.remove('aadfad22ca65e4ff09de37179f961d5b-.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017')`

Finally you can stop mongod on old hosts and remove everything from there.

Comment: what is the purpose of deleting all files from dbPath? just trying to understand what its dong

Comment: I just tried this and i have 2 issues. The original is still showing that replicasetIds do not match

Comment: The second issue is that after deleting everything in data/db/*, it shows as startup2 but it has an error : `durationMillis":0,"status":"InitialSyncOplogSourceMissing: No valid sync source found in current replica set to do an initial sync.","syncSource":":27017","operationsRetried":0,"totalTimeUnreachableMillis":0}]}}`

Comment: Actually you can skip deleting all files from dbPath. When you add the node to replica set, then the data will be deleted anyway before initial sync starts.

Comment: Regarding the error, did you add the node to replica set? What shows `rs.status()` (all members)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit rs.status is the 3rd and 4th snippets in the question =)

Comment: It says "(not reachable/healthy)" - did you start the MongoDB? Is connection blocked by firewall or missing TLS/SSL certificate?

Comment: yes the basic message is not reachable/healthy but the actual problem is stated `                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "replica set IDs do not match, ours: 628c90e7c07f5017faff8b75; remote node's: 628b8b76ab0cdc7f9158b23b",`

which suggests it is recognizing the other node